# Как c помощью jquery посчитать количество элементов td в столбце с определенным значением?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачку. Как посчитать количество td в таблице, именно в столбце с определенным классом и с определенным значением .
Количество элементов считает, а как посчитать именно со значением 'ok' ?

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>123</td>
   <td>123</td>
   <td>123</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td id='status'>123</td>
   <td id='status'>ok</td>
   <td id='status'>ok</td>
 </tr>
```

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: './save',
        data: { id: idp, status: status},
        success:function(res)
        {

            if(res == 'yes')
            {
              var nnn = $('.status').length;
              alert(nnn);
            }
       }
})
```

Comment: У вас в примере нету столбцов с определенным классом.

Answer (score 0):

через селектор :contains('content')

```js
console.log($('.status:contains("ok")').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>123</td>
   <td>123</td>
   <td>123</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td class='status'>123</td>
   <td class='status'>ok</td>
   <td class='status'>ok</td>
 </tr>
```

Вместо id используйте class, нельзя чтобы повторялись с id

UPDATE:

**Stepan Kasyanenko** написал

> Вы же понимаете, что это не совсем правильно? Потому что
>   :contains("ok") также посчитает, например, cookies.

В таком случае можно использовать filter

```js
const count = $('.status').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().trim() === 'ok'
}).length

console.log(count)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>123</td>
   <td>123</td>
   <td>123</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td class='status'>123</td>
   <td class='status'>ok</td>
   <td class='status'>ok </td>
   <td class='status'>cookies</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что это не совсем правильно? Потому что `:contains("ok")` также посчитает, например, `cookies`.

Comment: А у меня почему то не работает?  Считает общее количество ячеек не смотря на содержимое. Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: У меня class... то вручную писал вопрос и натупил

Comment: Я непонял немного, почему оно должно посчитать и cookies вместе с ok ?

Comment: co**OK**ies, то есть contains работает если находит подстроку, а не если оба текста одинаковы

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо!